# How do I add text to a input element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to add some text to an input element using a button. I have so far tried modifying .textContent - which does actually appear to modify the textContent, but this does not show up in the image box. Adjusting the .value does not seem to work.

My code:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".row button");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)  {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector("input").value += buttons[i].value;
    })  
}
```

Every solution I have read online just suggests modifying the .value of the input element, which is not working for me, so I am at a loss.

EDIT: Thanks everyone, such a silly thing to overlook.

Comment: input element is good, but buttons elements can not have a value attribute, so, there is noting to add...

Comment: Please provide the HTML that accompanies this. Preferably as a [MCVE]. What is the text you want to append?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the value property should work for you. Your problem lies in this statement:

`value += buttons[i].value`

Buttons don't have a value unless you specify one. The inner text of a button is accessed using the `innerHTML` or `innerText` properties, not the `value` property:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const input = document.querySelector("input");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   input.value += button.innerText;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">bleh</button>
```

With buttons, the value property is used for [PHP form submission](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp), not storing textual data.

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple buttons. [Don't use fat arrow functions for event listeners](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/when-you-should-not-use-arrow-functions/#:~:text=An%20arrow%20function%20doesn%27t,that%20uses%20the%20arguments%20object.)

Comment: ^ this is very true, keep this in mind OP. I was just doing a quick demonstration and used an arrow function; however, in practice, you shouldn't use them for event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set the value for the input field based on the button's display text?

If so, you can attempt to replace buttons[i].value with buttons[i].textContent

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button.innerHTML` to assign the input value

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>

    <script>
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
      const input = document.querySelector("input");
      buttons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
          input.value += button.innerHTML;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```